# In html anchor tags pointing to files via href="file:///.........", what is the "file:///" part known as?

Tags: html

I'm searching for some terminology so I can better catalog this fact in my mind when I point webpages to local files as I do in my analysis work. I want to know what is the `file:///` part called in an address. A file escape? A file protocol? What is it and what is it called?

Basically if I break down the anchor element like this, what would one label for the ??????? section with?

```
<TAG ATTRIBUTE="????????-------PATH-------" />
<a   href     ="file:///c:/Temp/MyText.txt" />
```

I discovered the need for this when linking directly to folder paths from my html. The behavior I wanted was to open the folder in Explorer, which works in Internet Explorer when there are no spaces in the path. However when paths contain spaces the link would render in the html with %20 for spaces and would trigger an attempt to open the folder in the browser as if it were a file which did not work. Putting the `file:///` thing resolved it, but what is that thing called?

Comment: I believe it's generally referred to as the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's officially referred to as the *scheme* ([see here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)), and colloquially often referred to as the *protocol*.

The portion you are referring to doesn't actually contain the last/third '/'. That is the first character of the *path* portion of the URL. This is tricky in your case, since on the filesystem, Windows' paths start with something like c:/. It makes more sense on a unix-type system, where the base of the filesystem is '/', so 'file:///mydir' would map to '/mydir' on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the protocol. It tells the client how the request should be processed.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the URI Scheme.
Check out:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier#Syntax